# mozIStorageConnection and asynchronous lastInsertRowID

Tags: javascript, sqlite, firefox-addon, xpcom

There's [pointed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/mozIStorageConnection#Attributes) in the docs, that we can't rely on lastInsertRowID property when working in async mode. In fact, when inserting 1K records into the database, the lastInsertRowID property is always equal 1K in "handleCompletion" function. Is there any way to get the last inserted id asynchronously?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to [get a meaningful rowid](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html)

Comment: But how does WebDatabase handle this problem? There is resultSet.insertId in its callbacks, so why doesn't mozIStorageConnection support it?